# What curvature conditions make a surface rigid?

Tags: surfaces, curvature, rigid-transformation

Consider a compact surface $S$, possibly with boundary, embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the induced Riemannian metric.  I believe that if $S$ has constant positive Gaussian curvature (that is, $S$ is a piece of a sphere), it is rigid.  Here rigid means that all isometric embeddings are related by rigid transformations of the ambient space.

Are surfaces with nonconstant positive curvature also rigid?  Conversely, if $S$ has negative curvature, is it always locally nonrigid (a sufficient small neighborhood of any point is nonrigid)?

Comment: When you say "closed surface"... you mean "closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$"?  Or something else?

Comment: @Geoffrey: "closed manifold" usually means "compact manifold without boundary." Presumably you're using it to mean something else since your surface may have boundary.

Comment: Yes: Fixed "closed" to "compact".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rigidity of closed surfaces of positive curvature in $R^3$ is a theorem by S. Cohn-Vossen from 1927. See for instance 
"Isometric Embedding of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces" by Q.Han, theorem 8.1.2.

As for $C^2$-smooth closed surfaces of negative curvature in $R^3$, they do not exist; hence, one can say that they all are rigid.

Comment: By "closed surface," you mean "compact surface without boundary," yes?  I mention this because the OP may mean something different.

Comment: Yes, I mean closed = compact without boundary. That's usual terminology. I am pretty sure that if you allow boundary, the result is false.

Comment: Are there any rigidity theorems that do allow boundary, possibly with restricted motion on the boundary?  Is there any answer to the converse part of my question (whether negative curvature always means nonrigid in some sense)?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving: Yes, but the boundary is required to remain fixed (as well as the normal vector fields to the boundary also should be fixed: This is akin to fixing boundary conditions in some boundary value problem). See the same book, discussion after the theorem.

Comment: @studiosus. Boundary as well as the normal vector fields to the boundary fixed makes _any_ attached surface rigid, Right?

Comment: @Narasimham: Yes if by "any" you mean "positively curved".

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving: Yes there are rigidity theorems for positively curved surfaces with boundary. It is sufficient to fix only a segment of the boundary. See the paper "Rigidity of nonnegatively curved surfaces relative to a curve", by myself and Joel Spruck, posted at https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02580. The paper contains many references.

Answer (score 1):

Can we then generalize with two statements in the following way?

[image: Const_pos&neg_K_Combo]

1. All closed compact smooth surfaces of arbitrary Gaussian curvature and $ 4 \pi$ integral curvature  are rigid. Example surface shown above composed of continuous constant positive and negative regions is rigid..(please ignore all the lines drawn on the surface).
2. All arbitrary compact smooth surfaces with boundary condition fixed as in eigenvalue problems or as in mechanics of materials finite element structural deformation problems in which all six degrees of freedom are annulled, are rigid.

EDIT: I shall delete above image after sometime, in view of error (that no one pointed out ) I find subsequent to posting -- As second order derivatives along meridian are discontinuous, it is particularly not a good example. For further discussion, please consider the following surface formed by displaced revolved cosine curve $ y = 2 + cos(x) $  where edges $x= 0$ and $ x =  \pi$ are fixed in the manner of Eigenfunction solutions or FEA.

Can it then be mathematically considered rigid by satisfaction of above two conditions?

[image: EdgesFixedRigidSurface?]